# Create an instance of a Django model with a FileField

Tags: django, django-models

How do I create an instance of a Django model with a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)?

For example, given a simple model

```
from django.db import models

class FileModel(models.Model):
    model_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

How can I create an instance of `FileModel`, passing in an existing file for the `model_file` field?

Answer (score 6):

You can open the existing file on the filesystem, wrap it in a Django [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-file-object) instance, and pass that in to the field directly:

```
>>> from django.core.files import File
>>> from myproject.myapp.models import FileModel
>>> with open('/path/to/existing_file.txt') as f:
...     wrapped_file = File(f)
...     m = FileModel(model_file=wrapped_file)
...     m.save()
...
>>> m.model_file.name
u'files/existing_file.txt'
```